# Function with several complex rules

Tags: r, function, dplyr, data.table

In my case:

```
# Open dataset
library(dplyr)
my.ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/test_ants.csv")
my.ds
# days nest       AT
# 1     0    2  10.9200
...
# 54  259 1067   0.9600
# 55  349 1067   0.9600

# Class size
my.ds$ClassType <- cut(my.ds$AT,breaks=c(-Inf,1,2.9,8.9,24.9,49.9,Inf),right=FALSE,
                          labels=c("Class_0_1","Class_1_3","Class_3_9","Class_9_25","Class_25_50","Class_50"))
```

I'd to calculate a ratio variable `velocity` with the following rules:

```
if (my.ds$nest<1000 & my.ds$ClassType!="Class_0_1") { #1)  If `nest` is < 1000 - considering "Class_1_3" to "Class_50"

counts <- my.ds%>%group_by(nest)%>%summarize(N=length(unique(ClassType)))

my.ds.3 <- my.ds%>%group_by(nest)%>%dplyr::summarize(ClassType=ClassType,max_AT=max(AT))
my.ds.3$class_max<- as.numeric(gsub('Class_[^_]*[^_]_', '', my.ds.3$ClassType)) # Max class value - second unscore

if(counts$N>1 | my.ds.3$max_AT>my.ds.3$class_max){ #If `ClassType` do not change by nest during the time or `AT` enter but dont leave the `ClassType`, don't calculate `velocity` (In my case `nest`2 and 7). or ooking for the last `ClassType` before `AT` enter and calculate the `velocity` between the last `ClassType` and the current `ClassType` for nest,

nests <- unique(rbind(counts$nest,my.ds.3$nest))
my.ds.2 <- my.ds[my.ds$nest %in% nests,]

my.ds.2$velocity <- c(0,diff(my.ds.2$AT))/c(0,diff(my.ds.2$days)) 

my.ds.2 <- %>% 
  group_by(nest,ClassType)%>%
  summarize(velocity=mean(velocity)) %>%
  complete(ClassType, tidyr:fill = list(velocity = NA)) %>%
  fill(velocity, .direction = "downup") # If lag any `ClassType` in "Class_1_3" to "Class_50" in a class more than `AT` value in the time 0, the class not present is the `velocity` value of the last `ClassType` for nest.

} 

} else { #If nest is >= 1000 - just considering "Class_0_1" `velocity` is `c(0,diff(AT))/c(0,diff(days))` by `days` for each nest too.

my.ds$velocity <- c(0,diff(my.ds$AT))/c(0,diff(my.ds$days)) 

}
```

My desirable output is:

```
# nest  ClassType   velocity
# 3 Class_ 1_3  0.224285714
# 3 Class_ 3_9  0.224285714
# 3 Class_ 9_25 0.224285714
# 3 Class_ 9_25 0.021463415
# 3 Class_ 9_25 0.306481481
# 4 Class_ 1_3  0.0075
# 4 Class_ 1_3  0.015714286
# 4 Class_ 1_3  0
# 4 Class_ 1_3  0
# 4 Class_ 1_3  0
# 4 Class_ 1_3  0
# 4 Class_ 1_3  0.289183673
# 4 Class_ 3_9  0.289183673
# 10    Class_9_25  0.263448276
# 10    Class_9_25  -0.015238095
# 10    Class_9_25  0.383809524
# 10    Class_25_50 0.383809524
# 10    Class_25_50 0.005454545
# 10    Class_25_50 0.457352941
# 10    Class_25_50 0
# 10    Class_25_50 0
# 10    Class_25_50 0.517959184
# 10    Class_50    0.517959184
# 10    Class_50    0.944634146
# 10    Class_50    0.73962963
# 1066  Class_0_1   0.002003448
# 1066  Class_0_1   0.000936585
# 1066  Class_0_1   0
# 1066  Class_0_1   0
# 1066  Class_0_1   0
# 1066  Class_0_1   0.000274286
# 1066  Class_0_1   0
# 1067  Class_0_1   0.002531034
# 1067  Class_0_1   0.000453659
# 1067  Class_0_1   0.001714286
# 1067  Class_0_1   0.001111765
# 1067  Class_0_1   0
# 1067  Class_0_1   0.020177143
# 1067  Class_0_1   0
# 1067  Class_0_1   0
```

Please any help with it?

Comment: What is `ds.calc`?

Comment: The desired output is unclear to me. Why does 0.224 "belong" to ClassType 1 when it represents the ratio between the last ClassType 1 and the first ClassType 4, but 0.306 "belongs" to ClassType 5 when it is comparing backwards from ClassType 4 to ClassType 5?

Comment: Thanks Joe!! `ds.cal` is a not successful tentative that I tried. Really 0.224 "belong" to the ClassType1 because a don't have ClassType2 and 3. In my case 0.94 (ClassType1) jump to 11.93 (ClassType4).